# Convert string numpy.ndarray to float numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, string, numpy

I have one problem. How can I convert:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([['0.1 0.2 0.3'], ['0.3 0.4 0.5'], ['0.5 0.6 0.7']])
```

To:

```
b = np.array([[0.1,0.2,0.3], [0.3,0.4,0.5], [0.5,0.6,0.7]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Here is a possible approach:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([['0.1 0.2 0.3'], ['0.3 0.4 0.5'], ['0.5 0.6 0.7']])

# Create a placeholder list
b = []

for element in a:
  # use a list comprehension to
  #     * take the zeroeth element in each row of the 'a' array and
  #       split the string on spaces
  #     * parse through each substring thus produced
  #     * convert each of those substrings into floats
  #     * store it in the list called temp.

  temp = [float(num) for num in element[0].split()]

  # Add each temp list to the parent list 'b'
  b.append(temp)

# Convert b into an np.array
b = np.array(b)
```

## Without the comments

This looks like this:

```
b = []

for element in a:
    temp = [float(num) for num in element[0].split(' ')]
    b.append(temp)
b = np.array(b)
```

## Yields:

```
array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
       [0.3, 0.4, 0.5],
       [0.5, 0.6, 0.7]])
```

## An alternate approach:

I tend to like this as an approach since it uses the native casting abilities of numpy. I have not tested it, but I would not be surprised if that produces a speedup in the conversion process for large arrays.

```
# transform 'a' to an array of rows full of individual strings
# use the .astype() method to then cast each value as a float
a = np.array([row[0].split() for row in a])
b = a.astype(np.float)
```

Hattip to @ahmed_yousif

Comment: You can do the casting in the `np.array` expression: `a = np.array([...], dtype=float)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm leaving this answer for a reference to those who are looking for a vectorized NumPy approach. TL;DR: it is not fast, use `np.array([row[0].split() for row in a], dtype=float)` as in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55607774/7851470).

---

I was looking for a vectorized approach to this problem and came up with the following solutions.

Using [`np.char.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.split.html#numpy.core.defchararray.split):

```
import numpy as np


def to_numeric1(array, sep=' ', dtype=np.float):
    """
    Converts an array of strings with delimiters in it 
    to an array of specified type
    """
    split = np.char.split(array, sep=sep)
    without_lists = np.array(split.tolist())
    corrected_dimension = np.squeeze(without_lists)
    return corrected_dimension.astype(dtype)
```

And using [`pd.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#splitting-and-replacing-strings):

```
import pandas as pd


def by_pandas(array, sep=' ', dtype=np.float):
    df = pd.DataFrame(array)
    return df[0].str.split(pat=sep, expand=True).to_numpy(dtype=dtype)
```

Unfortunately, both solutions are **slower** than native Python loops as in [E. Ducateme's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55607774/7851470):

```
a = np.array([['0.1 0.2 0.3'], ['0.3 0.4 0.5'], ['0.5 0.6 0.7']]*10000)

%%timeit
native_python_loop(a)
# 57.8 ms ± 526 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit
to_numeric1(a)
# 86.6 ms ± 122 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit
to_numeric2(a)
# 79.8 ms ± 1.11 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

As stated in the [comment by hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55607559/convert-string-numpy-ndarray-to-float-numpy-ndarray/57039691#comment100613811_57039691):

> The `np.char` functions apply Python string methods to each element of
>   the array. They are a convenience, but they do not improve speed.
>   NumPy doesn't have fast compiled code that operates on the contents of
>   strings. It depends on existing Python code for that. 'vectorization'
>   in the common numeric sense does not exist for strings.

---

Ideally, the first solution could be as fast as the native Python loops and have less lines of code. The problem is with returned values of `np.char.split`:

```
>>> a = np.array([['0.1 0.2 0.3'], ['0.3 0.4 0.5'], ['0.5 0.6 0.7']])
>>> np.char.split(a)
array([[list(['0.1', '0.2', '0.3'])],
       [list(['0.3', '0.4', '0.5'])],
       [list(['0.5', '0.6', '0.7'])]], dtype=object)
```

It returns a NumPy array of NumPy arrays of lists of strings which should be further processed to a normal 2D NumPy array, and I assume that this processing takes lots of time. As [hpaulj said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55607559/convert-string-numpy-ndarray-to-float-numpy-ndarray/57039691#comment100614515_57039691): "*`[i.split() for i in a]` and `np.char.split(a)` take basically the same time*"

There is an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/14014) that proposes changes to this function, so it would return the following instead:

```
array([['0.1', '0.2', '0.3'],
       ['0.3', '0.4', '0.5'],
       ['0.5', '0.6', '0.7']], dtype='<U3')
```

Comment: The `np.char` functions apply Python string methods to each element of the array.  They are a convenience, but they do not improve speed.  `numpy` doesn't have fast compiled code that operates on the contents of strings.  It depends on existing Python code for that.  'vectorization' in the common numeric sense does not exist for strings.

Comment: `pandas` doesn't use the `numpy` string dtypes; instead it uses `object` dtype - so its strings are regular Python strings.

Comment: `[i.split() for i in a]` and `np.char.split(a)` take basically the same time.

Comment: @hpaulj Well, that's unfortunate. Thanks for the info! I would like to add a note about this in the answer, but I can't find anything in the docs on this matter. I also searched the sourcecode, and I can see that `char.split` simply calls [`_vec_string`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/deea4983aedfa96905bbaee64e3d1de84144303f/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c#L3805), but from there I don't know what to look for as I'm not familiar with C internals of NumPy.

Comment: `numpy` is primarily a numeric package; strings are handled by treating them as blocks of bytes (4 bytes per unicode character).    Look at `_vec_string_no_args` (just above).  It constructs a `out_iter` (a `np.nditer` like object), and iterates, calling `PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(method, item, NULL)` for each element.  That's what I mean by calling the `astr.split()` method.  Python developers put a lot of work into handling strings (both byte and unicode); why should `numpy` developers duplicate that?

Answer (score 0):

```
b = []
for ai in a:
  temp=[]
  for b in ai[0].split(' '):
     temp.append(float(b))
  b.append(temp)

b = np.array(b)
```

You iterate through all strings, split them on a space, and typecast them to float

Comment: it throw `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'`

Comment: could you please give to error stack at which point does it give error?

Comment: At this line `b.append(temp)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with nested lists and then reshaping them.

```
b = [ float(h) for j in [i[0].split(" ") for i in a  ]for h in j ]
b = np.asarray(b).reshape(3,3)
```

Hope this helps.

@E. Ducateme Solution is pretty compressed also.

Answer (score 0):

first you will map every item in the array by spiting it into float strings then apply `x.astype(np.float)` function to convert to float

```
import  numpy as np

x = np.array([['0.1 0.2 0.3'], ['0.3 0.4 0.5'], ['0.5 0.6 0.7']])    
x = np.array(list(map(lambda z: z[0].split(),x)))
y = x.astype(np.float)
print(y)
```

result:

```
[[0.1 0.2 0.3]
 [0.3 0.4 0.5]
 [0.5 0.6 0.7]]
```