# Convert a numpy array of strings to a numpy matrix

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, character

So I have a numpy array of strings that contain numeric values separated by spaces, for example:

```
np.array(['1 2', '3 4'])
array(['1 2', '3 4'], dtype='<U3')
```

and I want to convert it to a numerical matrix like:

```
np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
array([[1, 2],[3, 4]])
```

I'm looking for an operation that can leverage numpy vecotrized operations, as speed is important here. The rows have length 2 in this example, but I need a general approach with an arbitrary row length.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string numpy.ndarray to float numpy.ndarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55607559/convert-string-numpy-ndarray-to-float-numpy-ndarray)

Comment: I came up with two vectorized solutions using [`np.char.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.split.html#numpy.core.defchararray.split) and [`pd.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#splitting-and-replacing-strings) but both of them are slower than the native Python loops in the accepted answer of the duplicate target.

Comment: @Georgy Can you post these solutions, maybe they are faster with bigger arrays, which is my case

Comment: Posted it under [the duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57039691/7851470)

Comment: @Georgy Thanks! I think the solution with np.char.split should be the fastest, I posted an issue in the numpy tracker

Comment: `np.char` functions are not faster; they just apply string methods to each string in the array.  There's no specialized `numpy` code to deal with the contents of strings.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach assuming nonnegative ints coming in pairs of two separated by a single space:

```
def to_num(x):                                          
    y = (x[:,None].view(np.int32)-48)*10**np.arange(x.itemsize//4-1,-1,-1)                    
    splt = y.argmin(1)                                                                        
    z = np.take_along_axis(y.cumsum(1),np.column_stack([splt-1,np.full(*y.shape-np.arange(2))]),1)
    z[:,1]+=10**(y.shape[1]-splt-1)*16-z[:,0]                                                    
    z[:,0]//=10**(y.shape[1]-splt)                                                               
    end = (y[:,::-1]>=0).argmax(1)
    z[:,1]+=np.concatenate([[0],48*np.cumsum(10**np.arange(end.max()))])[end]
    z[:,1]//=10**end
    return z
```

For example, 10^6 pairs take roughly 3 secs on my machine:

```
from timeit import timeit

x = np.random.randint(0,1000000,(1000000,2))
x = np.array([" ".join(map(str, y)) for y in x.tolist()])

(to_num(x) == [[int(z) for z in y.split()] for y in x.tolist()]).all()
# True
timeit(lambda:to_num(x), number=10)
# 2.9360161621589214
```

Comment: This seems to work, but it assumes that each row has length 2, and I'm interested in arrays with bigger rows, I'll add the info to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If it dont have to be that fast you could iterate element-wise over it and then apply:

```
def seperate_sting(s):

    split_numbers = s.split(' ')
    output = np.asarray(split_numbers).astype(int)

    return output


seperate_sting('1 1')
>>> array([1, 1])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but speed is critical here, I was looking for some type of vectorized operation. I will add the info to the question.

Comment: are there int values only? And are they resticted to [0,9]?

Comment: Yes, they are integers, but they are not restricted to [0,9]

Answer (score 0):

First, try to split your string with the white space, and when it's done check for the function [numpy.asmatrix()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.asmatrix.html)

Comment: `np.matrix(';'.join(a))` uses the ''1 2; 3 4" syntax that `np.matrix` accepts.  But this is slower than the list comprehensions.  `np.matrix` still has to use string operations to split the lines and numbers, just reversing our join.  It doesn't use fast compiled code to do that.